# rspec expectations change depending on other expectations existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a rails app tested with rspec using factorybot.
Users have many entries. Entries belong to a category.
Users have many categories through entries.

I created a user and put an expectation in to confirm the user had zero entries. Then I did a post request to create a new entry and category. The post request is successful and a new entry and category are created but my expectations fail in strange ways.

`let(:user) {create(:user)}
expect(user.categories.length).to eq(0)
expect(user.entries.length).to eq(0)
post "/api/v1/entries", params: valid_params, headers: { "Authorization" => "#{jwt}" }
expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
expect(user.categories.length).to eq(1)
expect(user.entries.length).to eq(1)`

If I have expectations for the users entries and categories being 0 and 1 the second set fails for them being 1. If I take out the first set of expectations for 0 the second set for 1 pass. Is there some rule in rspec that I am missing that changes behavior when testing the same value twice?

Comment: what should be happening is that `user.categories` and `user.entries` are cached due to the first call to `expect` = `0`. That's why removing those first expectations make your second expectations pass. So, before doing your second expectations just do a `user.reload` and then `expect(user.categories.length).to eq(1)`. That should work.

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much @fanta! Didn't even think about caching.